# Convert objects in c++

Tags: c++

I dont understand how the convert works..
code for example:

```
class Base
{
 private:
   int days;
 public:
   Base(int d):days(d){}
   virtual void somefunc..
   ...
};

class DayInYear:public Base
{
 public:
   DayInYear(int diy):Base(diy){}
   ...
}

class Month:public Base
{
 private:
   int month;
 public:
   Mounth(int dm,int m):Base(dm),month(m){}
   ...
}

int main()
{
 Base *arr[2] = {new DayInYear(100),new Month(20,4)};
 ...
}
```

And my question is how can I convert the type Month to type DayInYear ?

Comment: There isn't some sort of general solution applicable here, if that's what you're asking. As for a specific solution: your variable names (`d`, `diy`, `dm`, `m`, etc.) are not particularly descriptive, and it's hard for us to help you properly add to your code without understanding what it already does.

Comment: Class DayInYear counting days in the year, and Class Month, counts several months and days have passed since the beginning of the year (eg, 3 months and 20 days)

Comment: You won't be able to perform the conversion at all without knowing what year it is. (The first day of March is either the 60th or the 61st day of the year.)

Comment: For that matter the month has 30 days

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not be able to convert the types automatically for you since they are not sufficiently related.

You *could* build a *cast operator* in the `Month` class. This would have the prototype

```
operator DayInYear() const;
```

and returns a `DayInYear` object.

Then you could write `(DayInYear)m;` where `m` is a `Month` instance.

Comment: Bathsheba  and   Yochai Timmer

Both of you have specified the option of the operator, it seems to me the most efficient and optimal, I can be impertinent and ask to see the execution? please

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 ways.

Either make a constructor for `DayInYear` that takes a `Month` :

```
class DayInYear:public Base
{
 public:
   DayInYear(Month m) { //Create a DayInYear from Month }
   ...
}
```

Or, create a cast operator in `Month` that provides a `DayInYear` :

```
class Month:public Base
{
  public:
   operator DayInYear() const { //create a DayInYear  }
   ...
}
```

Or implement both.

This is a thing a lot of people get confused by when using C style casts:

```
Month m;

DayInYear day1 = DayInYear(m); //DayInYear constructor

DayInYear day2 = (DayInYear)m; //Cast Operator
```

Comment: I'd prefer this answer to mine if you make the cast operator `const`.

Comment: Bathsheba  and   Yochai Timmer

Both of you have specified the option of the operator, it seems to me the most efficient and optimal, I can be impertinent and ask to see the execution? please

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying you don't "understand how the convert works" I assume you are referring to this line of code:

```
Base *arr[2] = {new DayInYear(100),new Month(20,4)};
```

With this line of code there is technically no conversions being made, instead this is the concept of polymorphism. In object oriented programming languages such as C++, polymorphism refers to the idea that a single object can take many different forms. In the example you showed above, DayInYear and Month are not really being converted to the Base type. Both these classes inherit from base and therefore they can be referred to as Base. All of the other data held by DayInYear and Month is still there, it is just unable to be accessed when being assigned to its superclass of Base. These objects, when assigned to its superclass Base, can only be interacted with as if they were Base objects, however behind the scenes they are still the objects you created them as. Polymorphism is the key idea here and a very important concept to understand with object oriented programming, you can check out the following link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Now as for you question on converting Month to DayInYear, I am unsure why you would want to do that. First of all it would make no sense for a Month to be a DayInYear since they are very different things. This would also result is a loss of data most likely since Month contains the month attribute, whereas DayInYear does not. If you feel that this conversion needs to be made however, you would have a couple choices. First is to have a constuctor in you DayInYear class that takes a Month as an argument to create a DayInYear object:

```
DayInYear(Month month) { //Code that converts Month to DayInYear }
```

Another option is to use an assignment operator which would allow to to make a direct assignment of Month to DayInYear:
In your DayInYear class:

```
DayInYear& operator = (const Month& month) { //code for assignment }
```

In main you could do this now:

```
Month month(2, 3);
DayInYear dayInYear = month;
```

The final option you have is to use a type cast operator in your Month class:

```
operator DayInYear() {//conversion code}
```

This would allow for a cast between the two to be made.

Hope this helps.